# How to exempt a given route pattern from an htaccess rule

Tags: regex, .htaccess

Okay so I have this site - **myweb.com**, and then I have APIs for it too hosted in a subdirectory of the domain - **myweb.com/api**.

When I try to force all redirections to **https://www.myweb.com**, my API breaks because it already uses **https://myweb.com/api**.

Below is my htaccess for the time being:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    Redirect /page/faqs https://www.myweb.com/faqs
    Redirect /page/about https://www.myweb.com/about

    SetEnv TZ Africa/Lagos
</IfModule>

Options -Indexes

<Files .env>
    order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule php5_module>
    php_flag asp_tags Off
    php_flag display_errors Off
    php_value max_execution_time 960
    php_value max_input_time 1920
    php_value max_input_vars 16000
    php_value memory_limit 16384M
    php_value post_max_size 384M
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2880
    php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
    php_flag zlib.output_compression Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
```

So basically, I want the below to redirect to **https://www.myweb.com**.

- http://myweb.com
- https://myweb.com
- http://www.myweb.com

However, let the below be exempted from the above rule:

- https://myweb.com/api

Comment: is url in fourth paragraph a typo?

Comment: @jhnc its actually a typo. pardon me ;)

Comment: please edit your question to have the correct url

Comment: @jhnc Sorry, I skipped that too. Done now and my htaccess code in it too. Thanks

Comment: @DegodTestra I see you've now included your `.htaccess` file, there doesn't appear to be anything in there completing redirects for `/api` to `www.` - so perhaps this is done via the PHP file? Or have you not included all the relevant configuration?

Comment: @DeanTaylor I have not done the configuration at all. I equally stopped other redirections because it breaks requests to **https://myweb.com/api**. So I will appreciate htaccess code that won't break it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated Answer

Now you have provided your `.htaccess` and discussed your issue it might be easier to just handle `/api` requests earlier in your redirect rules.

Add this after your first `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
    # If handling an /api request ignore other rewrite rules.
    RewriteRule ^/api index.php [L]
```

This will just pass the `/api` requests to your "front controller" and not process any other rewrite rules that come after (`[L]`).

---

#### Previous Answer

You probably want something similar to the following:

```
# Set %{ENV:PROTO} variable, to allow rewrites to redirect with the
# appropriate schema automatically (http or https).

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ - [env=proto:http]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # No action if host already starts with "www."
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

    # No action if the path part that starts with "/api"
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api

    # Redirect to include "www."
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:PROTO}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can find similar `.htaccess` examples in the [Apache HTTP server boilerplate configs](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache) project on GitHub.

Your HTTPS redirect would be separate to this you might want to look here for a specific example:
https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/src/rewrites/rewrite_http_to_https.conf

Comment: Tried your code above. Site redirected to www.myweb.com without the https and the myweb.com/api was not exempted.

Thanks for the response and anticipated reply too.

Comment: @DegodTestra - please edit your question to include your full `.htaccess` file - it's likely an order issue. Note the use of `[R=301,L]` where `[L]` indicates this is the "last" rewrite rule to follow, if you are using rewrite rules on your `/api` handling you might find adding the "last" indicator stops other rules from processing below causing undesired redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have edited the question to have my htaccess code in it as recommended.

Comment: @DegodTestra based on your comments I've added a perhaps simpler solution for your use case.